# My characters pose changes in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, pose-mode

I have 4 characters and 2 of the characters change their pose in the render (Cycles and Eevee).

[image: screenshot]

Here is the [blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rt_IqlqYqUUKhFAGuowvLQw8rMe90aEf/view?usp=sharing) (google drive)

Comment: Hello! Next time, please add a screenshot to your question. People who have the same problem and looking for answers don't want to download 200 MB just to see if this question is relevant to them. And the same goes for people who want to help you. Not everyone can just download 200 MB to get an idea of what this issue is about.

Comment: Is this an animation or just an image? The three characters in the front have [Mixamo rigs](https://www.mixamo.com/). The pregnant girl in the back has an [MBLab rig](https://mb-lab-community.github.io/MB-Lab.github.io/). The two that have the problem have an empty (T-Pose) action (*Armature|mixamo.com|Layer0*) If you remove the action in the *Action Editor* with the [X], they keep their poses.